# Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core' Version=4.1.0.0

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I keep getting this error message whenever I try to run my web forms application.

> Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I get these details in the assembly binding log:

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/MyApplication/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = E:\My\RE Subversion\My Application V2\MyApplication\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: E:\\MyApplication\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\User\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/fd2e9b7a/f0d1e515/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/fd2e9b7a/f0d1e515/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E://MyApplication/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E://MyApplication/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/fd2e9b7a/f0d1e515/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/fd2e9b7a/f0d1e515/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/MyApplication/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/MyApplication/bin/DotNetOpenAuth.Core/DotNetOpenAuth.Core.EXE.
```

I have updated my entityframework recently which lead me to reinstall the Microsoft.ASPNET.Membership.OpenAuth, but everything seemed to work fine later on, not sure what I did that caused that error.

Here's the details from my `web.config`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing the package from Package manager console.